# Как записать bytes, полученные из базы данных, в файл?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sql-server, файлы

c msqsql  могу доставать кучу бит строк, длина их 30000 символов

```
for row in cursor.execute("""select  e.ENTID,ENTTYPE,id.filename,id.type,d.DATA from ATTACHHD id
  join ATTACHDATA d on d.ATTACHKEY=id.ATTACHKEY1
  join ENTITY e on e.ATTACHID=id.ATTACHID
  where id.FILENAME='IMG_0472.jpg'"""):
    print(row.DATA)
```

один файл состоит из кучи bytes:

```
b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe1E\xfeExif'
b'"\x97s\x01\x96\x1f\xdc>\x95P'
b'o\x10\xb6\xa5\x14\xf7\x02c\x12\xc7'
b'\xdb\xee}\xfd\xa91\x97\xe5\xb6\n'
b'.\xe3\xdb\xda\x80\xb1\x925k\xa8'
b'2+\x02\xc8\x0fn\xe2\x86P\xb6'
b'\x9e\xa34\x05\xcc\x8b\x9dA-\x9e'
b'\x07\xa7\xe5\x8a\xa4\x8d\xeew\xda\xdd'
b'\xc7 U&\x1b\x1a#Y\x90j'
b'\x92i\x0f*\xa0p\xa8|\xcf\x9b'
```

как эту кучу записать в файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> один файл состоит из кучи bytes

Используйте цикл по результатам запроса в базу.

А раз, у вас `DATA` это массив байт, то используйте режим `wb` для записи байтов.

Попробуйте:

```
sql = """select  e.ENTID,ENTTYPE,id.filename,id.type,d.DATA from ATTACHHD id
  join ATTACHDATA d on d.ATTACHKEY=id.ATTACHKEY1
  join ENTITY e on e.ATTACHID=id.ATTACHID
  where id.FILENAME='IMG_0472.jpg'"""

with open('IMG_0472.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    for row in cursor.execute(sql):
        f.write(row.DATA)
```

Comment: я то брал по одной дате, и пытался их склеивать) та я не пробовал, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexanderKoval, если помогло, то отметьте как решенное :)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('text.txt', 'w')
f.write(row.DATA)
```

Comment: так не работает...  сломана jpg получается

Answer (score 0):

```
write_file = 'out2.CSV'

with open(write_file, 'wb') as fw:
    fw.write(b'\xff\xfeA\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00T\x00a\x00g\x00\x00L\x00i\x00b'
             b'\x00\t\x00V\x001\x001\x005\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t'
             b'\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\t\x00\r\x00\n')
    fw.write(b'\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00T\x00a\x00g\x00N\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00'
             b'\t\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00H\x00M\x00I\x00I\x00D\x00\t\x00A'
             b'\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00P\x00L\x00C\x00I\x00D\x00\t\x00D\x00a'
             b'\x00t\x00a\x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00\t\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r'
             b'\x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00\t\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00\t\x00A'
             b'\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00C\x00o\x00d\x00e\x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00'
             b'\t\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00N\x00a\x00m'
             b'\x00e\x00\t\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00T\x00a\x00g\x00D\x00a'
             b'\x00t\x00a\x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00\t\x00E\x00n\x00a\x00b'
             b'\x00l\x00e\x00A\x00d\x00d\x00r\x00T\x00a\x00g\x00D\x00a\x00t'
             b'\x00a\x00T\x00y\x00p\x00e\x00\t\x00D\x00e\x00s\x00c\x00r'
             b'\x00i\x00p\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00\r\x00\n')
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 1 - чем это принципиально отличается от кода в [принятом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1061173/1365)? 2 - вы пишите файл с расширением csv, как вы потом такой csv с бинарными данными открывать собрались?

Comment: ну мне нужен именно файл csv, для панели Kinco, а она понимает только такой формат этого файла, т.е. каждый символ в строке разделён дополнительным нулевым байтом, а начинаться первая строка должна с FF

Comment: @ИванНиколаев это похоже utf-16 с BOM (byte-order marker - маркер порядка байт). Но в целом не понятно зачем еще один ответ, показывающий как писать бинарные данные в файл, при том что уже есть другой более полный. Я бы сказал, что у вас скорее ответ на какой-то другой (незаданный) вопрос.